# How to import multiple projects into Eclipse using command line?

Tags: eclipse, import, eclipse-cdt

Is there anyway that I can use command line to import multiple projects into Eclipse workspace all at once?
I noticed that someone suggests using command line as follows:

> eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll {[uri:/]/path/to/project}

But I cannot figure out the {[uri:/]/path/to/project} part correctly. Any example?
Also, is the above command line the only way I can achieve this? (it seems like to depend on CDT?) Is there any other way I can do this in command line?

Thank you!

Comment: did you tried copying the project folders to workspace directly and see if they are available as projects

Comment: Hey did you find any answers yet? This would be a very powerful feature.

Answer (score 8):

The only documentation of `headlessbuild` I've found so far is the [source](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/internal/core/HeadlessBuilder.java). This reveals that the argument to `-importAll` should be the path to a directory containing all your projects. You can use -importAll repeatedly to import multiple trees of projects.

e.g. if you have the structure

```
tree/
  core/
    alpha/
      .project
    beta/
      .project
  edge/
    one/
      .project
    two/
      .project
```

Then this will build the four projects in a workspace `tree/workspace`:

```
cd tree
eclipse -nosplash -data workspace -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll core -importAll edge -build
```

On Windows, use `eclipsec.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse CDT provides tools to import projects via the command line. 
You can use the following command / options to do so.

```
eclipse -nosplash 
  -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild 
  -import     {[uri:/]/path/to/project} 
  -importAll  {[uri:/]/path/to/projectTreeURI} Import all projects under URI
  -build      {project_name | all} 
  -cleanBuild {project_name | all}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path for the url.  e.g. /usr/fred/foo

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

1. You can specify the `-import` option multiple times
2. Use Linux file path separators instead of the evil DOS separators (i.e. `/` instead of `\`).
3. The uri should point to a directory and not a project name.  So, if you have a project called `foo` in the directory `path/to/FooBar`, the option would be `-import path/to/FooBar`

Here is a real world example that I use.

```
eclipsec -noSplash -data "WORKSPACE2" -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild  -no-indexer  -import 21-6912-xx-xpathparser -import 21-6912-xx-xpathparser/lib
```

output:

```
Create.
Opening 'libxpathparser'.
Create.
Opening '21-6912-xx-xpathparser'.
Saving workspace.
```

Answer (score -3):

You can find list of eclipse runtime options here: Help > Workbench User Guide > Tasks.
Format : eclipse [platform options] [-vmargs [Java VM arguments]]

Comment: The path to the documentation is no longer correct.  However, the documentation that you intended to  direct people to does not in any way address importing projects.